# Trading view : Add a custom indicator to a chart embedded in my website

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

I have a code to embed the trading view chart to my website however the custom indicators are not getting added once the chart is embedded. What is the way to add a custom indicator to a trading view embedded chart? I tried adding an element to the studies array but its not working. Suggestions?

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<html>
<body>
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_8ba84"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL stock chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "autosize": true,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "dark",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "in",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": true,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "studies": [
    "boomhunter"
  ],
  "container_id": "tradingview_8ba84"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding custom studies to an embedded TradingView chart is not possible.

From the *Frequently Asked Questions* section of [the widget page](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/):

> #### I'd like to add a custom pine script to the widget.
>
> It is not possible to add pine scripts to widgets at this time. You can publish an idea with your script and embed it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the "studies" part and add them in there. [This site](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/) shows an example in the Embed Code section of the demo